# Text showing differently in Safari to Firefox & Explorer

Tags: css, text, safari, font-size

I have a page where my text font is set to a specific size, showing below:

Html:

```
<span>some text showing here</span>
```

CSS

```
span
{
 font-size: 1.1vw;
}
```

The above causes the text to look the same size in Firefox, Explorer & Chrome, but in Safari the text looks significantly smaller, as though I have set it at 0.5vw.

I have tried using .em instead of .vw, however this then does not seem to resize the text correctly when viewport size is reduced/increased, creating a whole different issue. I also have a CSS reset in place at the beginning of my code, to help with cross browser issues, but it still occurs.

Any ideas why the text size differs in Safari when using .vw, and what I can do to get round it?

Comment: Which version of Safari and using what OS?

Comment: Hi Paulie...I'm using Safari version 5.1.7 on Windows 7

Comment: `vw` is not supported by Safari 5.1 see [**CanIUse.com**](http://caniuse.com/#search=vw)

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for that. Do you know a way of testing what a page would look like on ios safari without the page being live - i.e testing the files before they are hosted?

Comment: Chrome's developer tools and emulation might be able to help.